# home page is not opening in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli, configuration

Home page is not responding in codeigniter I configured correctly, I tried to debug but cant found what is error

Please look at below code

**config/routes.php**

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
//$route['404_override'] = '';
//this for the admininstration console
$route['admin'] = 'admin/dashboard';
$route['admin/media/(:any)']= 'admin/media/$1';
```

**controllers/home.php**

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
                $this->load->model('Category_model');
                $this->load->model('Product_model');
                $this->load->model('Option_model');
                $this->load->model('ratenreview_model');

                //load Dentkart library
                $this->load->library('Banners');
                $this->load->library('Menus');
                $this->load->model(array('location_model'));
                $this->load->model('Customer_model');
        $this->load->model('Testimonial_model');
       $this->load->library('dentkart');
                $this->load->helper(array('formatting_helper'));
                $this->customer = $this->dentkart->customer();

    }
private function index() {

                $this->data['page'] = "Home";
                $this->ratenreview_model->ecash_event_date('dob');
                $this->ratenreview_model->ecash_event_date('clinic_anniversary');
                $this->ratenreview_model->ecash_event_date('marrg_aniversary');

                $arrCatHome  =array(440,468,472,568);
                for($i=0;$i<count($arrCatHome);$i++){

                        $data['arrCategories'][] = $this->Category_model->get_category($arrCatHome[$i]);
                        $data['products'][$arrCatHome[$i]] = $this->Product_model->get_homepage_category_products($arrCatHome[$i]);

                        foreach ($data['products'][$arrCatHome[$i]] as &$p){
                                $p->images  = (array)json_decode($p->images);
                                $p->options = $this->Option_model->get_product_options($p->id);
                        }
                }

                $data['arrShopByBrand'] = $this->Product_model->get_shop_brands();
                //$data['arrHomeProducts'] = $this->Product_model->getHomeProducts();
                //get all booktype
        //$data['arrBooktype'] = $this->Product_model->get_book_types();

        $data['arrTestimonial'] = $this->Testimonial_model->getTestimonialList();
        $this->load->view('vwHome',$data);
    }
}
```

**.htaccess**

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|jquery|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L]
```

and also tried to change defualt controller in routs its getting 404 error 
please help me how to solve issue

Answer (score 0):

`private function index() {` should be `public function index() {`

Router can't  see/display private methods. Private methods in controller should be used rarely and usually only for smaller "helper" functions for the class that are commonly used.

Comment: yes, i changed to public function index() still its not coming

Comment: Home needs to be `Home.php` as is case sensitive on Linux. Try going to index.php/home to see if that works atleast

Comment: I tried alex still not working, dont know where the isuue

Comment: I tried to change home to admin page then its showing 404 page not found @Alex

Answer (score 0):

Simply Change the `private function index()` in your `Home` controller to a public function

Answer (score 0):

change the route.php

```
 $route['default_controller'] = 'Home';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```